# Forwarding all received mail to another server in Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

We are moving away from our Exchange environment on a hosted server to one managed in-house, and I was wondering how to have the hosted Exchange forward all email received to the new server - the servers are not on the same network, and both have the same users setup.

Basically, I just need the hosted Exchange to act as a dumb relay - accept the mail, send it straight on to our new server without trying to deliver locally.

Is this possible?

Regards
Moo

Answer (score 0):

Some providers allow it, some do not. Take it up with their support desk.

Comment: Sorry, edited the question to be more clear - the server is hosted, but both the Exchange servers themselves are managed by ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change your MX record to point to the new server?

Comment: We have - however, due to the basics of DNS, some remote hosts will have the records cached and may still send mail to the old server.

Comment: Well then add a second MX with the same priority that points to the new server and then stop the SMTP service on the old server. This should force all sending servers to deliver to the new server as they'll be unable to connect to the first server. Then, when it's convenient for you, remove the first MX record.

Comment: Or have the old server relay them to the new one for a while?